# how to delete encrypted message

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

The encrypted message come from database.I need to delete that message like this :

```
 holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle("Delete")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to permanently delete the selected message?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                        String sender = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid() + receiverId;
                        database.getReference().child("Chats").child(sender)
                            .child(messages.getMessageId()).removeValue();
    //                            .setValue(null);
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }).show();
        return false;
    }
});
```

This code working in with out encrypting,  but  in my case my data coming in the encrypt file. anyOne have a idea how to delete that message ???

i need to delete encrypted message.

Comment: That sounds more like a permission issue than an encryption issue. Encryption shouldn't change anything in that regard.

Comment: Can you please show the data structure of your chat?

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to the `.removeValue()` operation, to see if something goes wrong?